# Class Based View - Fields aren't created in database (python Inherits\django cbv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database-migration, django-class-based-views

I'm trying create a model inherit following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-inheritance-in-python-3

Everything works. Can access **FirstName** property in child and show in view but when I run `makemigration/migrate`,inheriteds fields aren't created in table in database. (core-shark / core-trout)

What am I doing wrong? Is possible, using python inherits and CBV, to create fields in database by makemigration/migrate?

model.py

```
class Fish(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def swim(self):
        print("The fish is swimming.")

    def swim_backwards(self):
        print("The fish can swim backwards.")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fish'
        abstract = True     
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Shark(Fish):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Shark", skeleton="cartilage", eyelids=True):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.skeleton = skeleton
        self.eyelids = eyelids

    def swim_backwards(self):
        print("The shark cannot swim backwards, but can sink backwards.")


class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water ='', price = 0):
        self.water = water
        self.price = price
        super().__init__(self)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Trout'
```

view.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        sammy = Shark("Sammy")
        terry = Trout()
        terry.first_name = "Terry"

        context['sammy'] = sammy
        context['terry'] = terry
 
        return context
```

index.html

```
...
<body style="color:red">
    <h1>Fish Name: {{sammy.first_name}}</h1>
    <h1>Fish Name: {{terry.first_name}}</h1>
</body>
...
```

[image: INDEX.HTML showing inherited field]

[[image: mysql create only id default field][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODm8.png)

[project git](https://github.com/DiegoVenancioVieira/Sea.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Django Documentation for Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/), you need to define your database fields as Class attributes.

I.o.w:

```
class Fish (models.Model):
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name  = last_name
```

Doing so will allow them to be created in the database when you run the migration.